# Filtering values from a Datatable to be transferred to another Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, datatable

I have a Datatable that has a checkbox and a value, What I want is that when I click a button it would get all the checked boxes and their corresponding value and Add them to a blank Datatable. I not planning to save the data moved from 1 list to another, as there will be another functionality to confirm if I want to save the changes(not being asked in this question).

This is my html code:

```
  <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="uoListViewAirportSaved" EmptyDataText="No Data Found">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500px">
                    <tr>
                       <th runat="server">&nbsp;</th>
                    <th runat="server">Airport</th>
                    </tr>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftAligned">
                             <asp:CheckBox ID="uoCheckBoxSelect" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="leftAligned">
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="uoHiddenFieldAirport" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ColAirportCodeVarchar") %>' />
                                <asp:Label ID="uoLabelAirport" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("colAirportFullName")%>' />                         
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  width="500px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Airport</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" class="leftAligned">No Record</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>                
            </asp:ListView>
```

And the code when I click the add button:

```
    private void AddAirport() {
        CheckBox uoCheckBoxSelect;
        HiddenField uoHiddenFieldAirport;
        Label uoLabelAirport;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

        DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();

        string serviceProvider = GlobalCode.Field2String(Request.QueryString["pid"]);
        ///datatable with all list of airports
        dt = VendorMaintenanceBLL.GetServiceProviderAirportbyBrand(serviceProvider);
        ///datatable with provider's current airports
        dt2 = VendorMaintenanceBLL.GetServiceProviderAirportbyVendor(serviceProvider);


        foreach(ListViewItem item in uoListViewAirport.Items)
        {
            uoCheckBoxSelect = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("uoCheckBoxSelect");
            if (uoCheckBoxSelect.Checked == true)
            {
                uoHiddenFieldAirport = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("uoHiddenFieldAirport");
                uoLabelAirport = (Label)item.FindControl("uoLabelAirport");

                /// my new list should contain  the values from the checked values of the checkboxes
                        ???

            }
        }

    }
```

My Datatable contains the AirportID and the AirportStringName columns.

I found a code that I'm trying to replicate, logic-wise. However it is designed for a list:

```
            List<AirportDTO> listToBeAdded = new List<AirportDTO>();
    List<AirportDTO> listAdded = new List<AirportDTO>();

    listToBeAdded = GetAirportNotInUser(false, false);
    listAdded = GetAirportInUser(false);

    foreach (ListViewItem item in uoListViewAirport.Items)
    {
        uoCheckBoxSelect = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("uoCheckBoxSelect");
        if (uoCheckBoxSelect.Checked == true)
        {
            uoHiddenFieldAirport = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("uoHiddenFieldAirport");
            uoLabelAirport = (Label)item.FindControl("uoLabelAirport");

            var listToAdd = (from a in listToBeAdded
                             where a.AirportIDString == GlobalCode.Field2String(uoHiddenFieldAirport.Value)
                             select new
                             {
                                 AirportID = a.AirportIDString,
                                 AirportName = a.AirportNameString,
                             }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

I do not know how I would get the necessary data from the datatable as it is different from a list. Is there a way for me to do the same thing with DataTables the way lists were tackled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I really need to fix the problem yesterday, I decided to do the following.

What I did was just basic for loop, then inside compare each row and then just use `Datatable.ImportRow` and `DataTable.RemoveAt`. I also added a temporary Datatable for the changed lists.

```
        foreach(ListViewItem item in uoListViewAirport.Items)
        {

            uoCheckBoxSelect = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("uoCheckBoxSelect");
            if (uoCheckBoxSelect.Checked == true)
            {
                uoHiddenFieldAirport = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("uoHiddenFieldAirport");
                uoLabelAirport = (Label)item.FindControl("uoLabelAirport");

               string  HiddenFieldAirport = GlobalCode.Field2String(uoHiddenFieldAirport.Value);

               for (var f = 0; f < dt.Rows.Count; f++ )
               {

                   if (dt.Rows[f]["colAirportIDInt"].ToString() == HiddenFieldAirport)
                   {   
                       dt3.ImportRow(dt.Rows[f]);
                       dt.Rows.RemoveAt(f);
                   }
               }

            }

        }
```

The code is dirty, plus I had to sort it as well, but since I really needed it, I can make do with this.